# How to share generated qr code in React-Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I generated QR code using 'react-native-qrcode-svg', and I want to share this svg thru email or something like that using Share module of react-native.

```
import { Share } from 'react-native';
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';
render() {
    return (
        ....
        <QRCode
                color="#090909"
                value={this.props.myCode}
                size={150}
            />
       )
    }
....

 onPress = {()=>{
        Share.share({
             message: 'How I will send QR code image?'                          
             title: 'QR code',
        });
....
```

I guess that I need to get svg file handle and set it to the share module, but want to see sample code.

Answer (score 5):

Solution. Finally able to figure out how to share qr code.

```
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';
 <QRCode
          value={JSON.stringify({test: 'testdata'})}
          getRef={c => (this.svg = c)}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.saveQRCode}>
          <View style={styles.instructions}>
            <Text>Share QR code</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>


saveQRCode = () => {
    this.svg.toDataURL(this.callback);
  };



callback(dataURL) {
    console.log(dataURL);
    let shareImageBase64 = {
      title: 'React Native',
      url: `data:image/png;base64,${dataURL}`,
      subject: 'Share Link', //  for email
    };
    Share.open(shareImageBase64).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if we can pass a functional component as value in QRCode?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rn-qr-generator` module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-qr-generator). You need to pass `value` to the lib and it will return you `uri` and `base64` data of the generated QRCode

```
import RNQRGenerator from 'rn-qr-generator';

componentDidMount() {
    RNQRGenerator.generate({
      value: 'otpauth://totp/Example:alice@google.com?secret=JBSWY3DPEHPK3PXP&issuer=Example', // required
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      base64: false, // default 'false'
      backgroundColor: 'black', // default 'white'
      color: 'white', // default 'black'
    })
      .then(response => {
        const { uri, width, height, base64 } = response;
        this.setState({ imageUri: uri });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('Cannot create QR code', error));
  }
```

And later you can use `react-native-share` to share the image

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented it in my project. It is working properly. Please follow below steps

1. install [react-native-qrcode-image](https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/react-native-qrcode-image)

   `npm install git+https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/react-native-qrcode-image.git --save`
2. Install [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share)

   `npm install react-native-share --save`
3. [Link it with app](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share#manual-install)

   `react-native link react-native-share`
4. Use QRCode in your component

   ```
   import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-image';
   import Share from 'react-native-share';

   class Dashboard extends React.Component {
     static navigationOptions = {
       title: Strings.dashboardTitle
     };

     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.qrCode = '';
     }

     openShareScreen() {
       if (this.qrCode) {
         const shareOptions = {
           type: 'image/jpg',
           title: '',
           url: this.qrCode
         };
         Share.open(shareOptions)
           .then(res => console.log(res))
           .catch(err => console.error(err));
       }
     }

     render() {
       const { type, address } = this.state;
       return (
         <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.openShareScreen}>
           <View>
             <QRCode
               getBase64={base64 => {
                 this.qrCode = base64;
               }}
               value={address}
               size={150}
               bgColor="#FFFFFF"
               fgColor="#000000"
             />
           </View>
         </TouchableHighlight>
       );
     }
   }

   export default Dashboard;
   ```

Answer (score -1):

you can create variable like below to store share details

```
 let shareImageBase64 = {
      title: "React Native",
      message: "Hola mundo",
      url: MY_ICON_SVG,
      subject: "Share Link" //  for email
    };
```

then you can call it while pressing button or something like below

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
          Share.open(shareImageBase64);
        }}>
```

In here `MY_ICON_SVG` should be base64. You can create this kind of icon form svg using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-convert-image-to-base64 module.

```
import ImgToBase64 from 'react-native-image-base64';

ImgToBase64.getBase64String('file://youfileurl', (err, base64string) => doSomethingWith(base64string));
```

I didn't try this module. But i think this will work for u if not browse this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/212 there are some alternatives.

But if any of these couldn't get as working. You can do it by creating ".png" file qr code instead of ".svg" file then u can convert it into base 64 using library i before mentioned library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do i get file://youfileurl from qr code.

Comment: @Trinu it is uri of your image file. this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423067/how-to-get-absolute-path-of-a-file-in-react-native will help to get it

Comment: i dont want to save the qr code in iphone memory. Rather i want to directly share the qr code which is generated in the app and will share to whatsapp.

Comment: Ok how to access or how to get your qr code. Is there any refernce for it?

Comment: <QRCode
                color="#090909"
                value={this.props.myCode}
                size={150}
            /> This is how the qr code is being displayed. Now i am looking for a way to convert this qr code to an image. Do you know how to do this

Comment: In here https://github.com/awesomejerry/react-native-qrcode-svg, there is an example to get url from qrcode ->   saveQrToDisk() {
    this.svg.toDataURL((data) => {
     RNFS.writeFile(RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath+"/some-name.png", data, 'base64')
       .then((success) => {
        return CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath+"/some-name.png", 'photo')
       })
       .then(() => {
        this.setState({ busy: false, imageSaved: true  })
        ToastAndroid.show('Saved to gallery !!', ToastAndroid.SHORT)
       })
    })  

and it wrote as base64 did u try it ?

Comment: I want in ios not in android and that to without saving in to phone photos. Is that possible to convert that QR code into byte 64 image string?