# React native how to save image in application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to save images from camera roll internally in my app.

I've been using [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-crop-picker/v/0.4.2) to import the image's base64 data and saving it with AsyncStorage.

The problem is when it comes to render Images using base64 data, it's extremely slow.

I would like to save the images and have their URIs in order to render them faster.

Comment: Try rn-fetch-blob

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking it out :)

Comment: on iOS you cann not save the path for any image, because it would be always change. the better option is past the option `includeBase64:false`to your request object. try it and let me know if it now faster

Comment: Yes but I want to save images from camera roll internally in my app.

Comment: I am in the same spot as you. I am using `react-native-image-crop-picker` to select the file and then I used `react-native-fs` which has a method `.copyFile` to copy it to the App itself. I also asked a SO question if this is a best practice but no one answered.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link [How to get absolute path of a file in React-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423067/how-to-get-absolute-path-of-a-file-in-react-native/52551982#52551982)

This Link will help you in Implementation [Code Sample](https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker/issues/156#issue-362126174)

Once you get the absolute path of the file `rn-fetch-blob` package will help you store it your file system checkout this link [File system](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#file-system)

I hope this helps, do comment if any doubts !